# Angular DOM : Dom is not getting updated every 1000ms with $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, setinterval

[image link for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U52f.png) I'm trying to update angular dom every second with time data which is not updating even though on console $digest is running but its not updating value.

```
  angular.module('app').controller('mvCoursesDetailCtrl', function($scope, mvCourse, $routeParams,$interval) {

     $scope.test;

     $scope.course = mvCourse.get({_id:$routeParams.id}, (data)=> {
      console.log(data.published);
      console.log(data.endDate);
      let oneDay = 1000*60*60*24;
      let oneHour = 1000*60*60;
      let oneMinute = 1000*60;
      let oneSecond = 1000;
      let startDate = new Date();
      let startMonth = startDate.getMonth() + 1;
      let endDate = new Date(data.endDate);
       $interval(function () {
       $scope.test = Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneMinute)+" Minutes "+Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneSecond)+" s";
        console.log($scope.test);
      },1000);


     });
    });
```

This is where `test` variable is not getting updated

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>{{course .title}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Featured</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Published on</h3>
            <h4>{{course.published | date}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Status</h3>
            <h4 ng-show="course.status.toLowerCase() === 'open'">
              <mark class="open">{{course.status | uppercase}}</mark>
            </h4>
            <h4 ng-show="course.status.toLowerCase() === 'booked'">
              <mark class="booked">{{course.status | uppercase}}</mark>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Time Left</h3>
            <h4>{{test}}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Tags</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-repeat="tag in course.tags">{{tag}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Please guide me.

Comment: That usage of bold text and exclamation marks is rather unnecessary.

Comment: hahaha.. Ya thanks but thats not the answer I'm waiting for. Please help me solving this bug!! @MatusDubrava

Comment: We cannot run your code as it got "course" dependency, Could you share what error message you are getting?

Comment: Error is that it is not updating the my angular expression **{{test}}** even though in console $interval is triggering every sec but not updating anything!! @RTWorkSpace

Comment: By error I meant : error logged by Angular in Console .
There are two possibilities : either your controller is not working hence nothing is happening on UI else, there is syntax error in both case.. angular must have logged some error.. Could you paste that here

Comment: sure I have attached image file at the top with code for viewing my DOM please have a look @RTWorkSpace

Comment: The $scope.test; should be assigned with initial value ,

Comment: not working!! it get initialized to 0 to begin with but then ends with static time value and never gets updated again!! @RTWorkSpace

Answer (score 0):

Initialize "$scope.test;" with some value $scope.test=0;
If you don't initialize it , it remains NAN .

Comment: not working!! it get initialized to 0 to begin with but then ends with static time value and never gets updated again!!

Answer (score 0):

First - initialize $scope.test with some value, $scope.test = "";
Second - is you should use $scope.$apply() inside $interval method. $scope.$apply() will call $scope.$digest() to update changed model values to view.

Comment: no!! adding $interval does the same thing in angular i.e, it calls $scope.$apply internally in angular!! Doing so will throw an error on console as $digest running was running already.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code burns down to :

```
let startDate = new Date();
let endDate = new Date(data.endDate);
$interval(function () {
       $scope.test = Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneMinute)+" Minutes "+Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneSecond)+" s";
        console.log($scope.test);
      },1000);
```

Whatever your calculations go, both the `startDate` and `endDate` are fixed and hence your `$scope.test` will have a constant value (the value won't change). I think you need to be changing the variables, as to get the latest time in the $interval as:

```
$interval(function () {
       let startDate = new Date();
       $scope.test = Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneMinute)+" Minutes "+Math.ceil(Math.abs(((startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime())))/oneSecond)+" s";
        console.log($scope.test);
      },1000);
```

> This question has nothing to do with the scope not getting updated, actually your test value is not changing.

That's what I feel. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: not actually that was not the case!! Actually in my code i had inserted $interval in wrong place **$scope.course** as you can see and b'coz of that $interval was calling the same values again and again. What I did in the end is copied the **$interval** function outside **$scope.course** and placed it inside controller. Hence, it worked!!

Comment: Um, That means the service will be called every second, right? Was that your requirement?

Comment: no i didn't want that but I was doing that and so i was getting that error!!